# How do I remove "shop" from Astra Breadcrumbs?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, spectra, wordpress-theme-astra

I use Astra WordPress theme and on the shop page I see:
Home/Products/Shop

Is there any way to remove the "shop" by using action hooks? I have tried various filters but nothing seems to work.

By the way, I can't simply hide the last trail item since breadcrumbs are correct on other pages.

I tried various filters and actions, I have also tried contacting Astra Support

Comment: Hi Tomas and welcome to SO. Please include what you've tried as code in your question. Have you got any response from Astra Support, yet? Have you inspected the source code of Astra to see what filters/hooks are used in the breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can hide it by adding some CSS. To do so, first detect the class of the part you do not want to see (`Home/Products/Shop`), then use the following CSS code to get rid of that:

```css
.your-detected-class{display: non;}
```